# how do i specify a custom error page without setting defaultPath on httpErrors in the web.config?

Tags: asp.net, iis, error-handling

I'm currently working on deploying a asp.net website to a shared hosted environment, and this works as expected (404 pages render)

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/file-not-found.htm" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

but this doesn't (500 internal server error)

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultPath="error.htm" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/file-not-found.htm" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

I asked to take a look at the applicationHost.config and it has:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultPath="C:\inetpub\custerr\en-US\SSLRedirect.htm" lockAttributes="allowAbsolutePathsWhenDelegated,defaultPath">
```

So I'm assuming that the defaultPath as a locked attribute is the thing that's causing issues.

Because this is being deployed to a shared environment, the hosting company is not willing to modify the applicationHost.config to remove the lock on defaultPath - so is there any way to specify a default error page without unlocking the defaultPath attribute?

Comment: if anyone knows why its locked by default, or a non-code solution, would be keen to find out too :)

Comment: It's locked by default because having it unlocked in shared hosting environment would cause security issues: it would be possible for anyone to access private files of other users through absolute path in defaultPath.

Comment: @DimaStefantsov But could you use an absolute path if allowAbsolutePathsWhenDelegated is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In global.asax you could just implement Application_Error() and redirect to wherever you want?