# Web.config - Specify default error page for errors

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, web-config

I know I can specify error pages according to error type: **404**, **500**, ...

What I'm looking for is a default error page for any error I did *not* specify a page for. For example - if I only add a

```
<error statusCode="404"  responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/.../404.aspx"/>
```

and a **500** occurs - I want it to go to some `AnyError.aspx` . How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the `defaultPath` and `defaultResponseMode` attribute on your `<httpErrors>` like so:

```
<httpErrors mode="On" defaultPath="/AnyError.aspx" defaultResponseMod="ExecuteURL">
    <error statusCode="404"  responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/.../404.aspx"/>
</httpErrors>
```

Comment: Thanks. But as you can see (from the use of `responseMode`), I'm using <system.webServer> , unfortunately, adding <system.web> (with which your suggestion works) caused the <system.webServer> section to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I guess it's because of [this comment that I've now found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924448/how-do-i-specify-a-custom-error-page-without-setting-defaultpath-on-httperrors-i#comment14860679_7924448).